# My Activity Class can't view my layout resource

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity, android-xml

I'm working on a calculator project. The class where I' implementing the work can't see the XML layout. When I use `setContentView(R.layout.)`, it doesn't see any xml files. Although the welcoming class works fine and set its content view to the welcoming XML.

Can anyone tell me why this is an error?

Comment: Make sure your xml file doesn't have any errors.

Comment: Hello again, @Tharwat7.  Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you :).

Answer (score 5):

Here's a few things you can try:

- First, check for XML errors.  R will not generate if there are any XML errors.
- Then, try deleting your bin folder and doing a Project->Clean.
- Also, try adding `import my.package.name.R` at the header of your Activity.  Make sure that you are *not* using `import Android.R`.

Let me know if any of those work.

Comment: yes i cleaned it, still no differance..
look i have 2 classes, the welcoming class (welcome screen) and the calculation class. The welcoming class sees both XMLS, its the Calc class that sees none

Comment: Hmmm.. which R import are you using?  If it's `import android.R`, this can yield errors like this.  Make sure it's `import my.package.name.R`.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked,, both XMLs are visible now, but can you explain to me why does this make a differance?

Comment: @Tharwat7 If u explore your project folders within your IDE, you'll find there's generated R.java (But don't edit or delete it!), it stores the reference to your resources. Thus you should import this R.java, but not the import `android.R`